# Yahoo Pipes, simplejson and slashes

Tags: python, yahoo-pipes, simplejson

Im trying to use http://www.javarants.com/2008/04/13/using-google-app-engine-to-extend-yahoo-pipes/ as inspiration, but I'm having some troubles with the output.

Its obvious when testing with the console and the App Engine "django util simplejson":

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Google/google_appengine/lib/django
$ python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Dec  2 2008, 09:26:14) 
[GCC 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from django.utils import simplejson as json
>>> json.dumps('/')
'"\\/"'
>>> json.dumps('http://stackoverflow.com')
'"http:\\/\\/stackoverflow.com"
```

[As far as I can read](http://microformats.org/wiki/json) this is ok behavior:

> In JSON only the backslash, double
>   quote and ASCII control characters
>   need to be escaped. Forward slashes
>   may be escaped as in the URL example
>   below, but do not have to be.

But when inputting back to yahoopipes, they don't "unescape" the output and all my urls and html doesnt work.

should I really do a

```
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj).replace('\\/','/'))
```

?

==== Edit ===

To my great suprise I see that newest simplejson downloaded from simplejson site doesnt do the "slash" stuff :(
So the real issue is with app engines django.util.simplejson version?

=== Edit again ===

And now Ive created an issue in the tracker for it: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1128

Comment: Neither does django.util.simplejson from standard Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing here to see. The ticket is there, but thats it, as far as I can see